# How is "multiplexed async architecture" asynchronous?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency

From [Python in a Nutshell](https://books.google.com/books?id=FrCgDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA515&ots=1CruecHwu-&dq=multiplexed%20async&pg=PA515#v=onepage&q=multiplexed%20async&f=false)

> In  what  is  sometimes  known  as  **a  multiplexed  async 
>   architecture**,  your  code keeps track of the I/O channels on which
>   operations may be pending; when you can do no more until one or more
>   of the pending I/O operations completes, the thread running your
>   code goes into a blocking wait (this situation is usually referred to
>   as “your code blocks”), specifically waiting for any completion on
>   the relevant set of channels. When a completion wakes up the blocking
>   wait, your code deals with the specifics of that completion (such
>   “dealing with” may  include  initiating  more  I/O  operations), 
>   then,  usually,  goes  back  to  the blocking wait. Python offers
>   several low-level modules supporting multiplexed async architectures,
>   but the best one to use is the higher-level  selectors  module

1. The meaning of "multiplexed" in "multiplexed async" can't be
   explained by its definition from
   http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/multiplexing

   > Multiplexing (or muxing) is a way of sending multiple signals or streams of information over a communications link at the same time
   >   in the form of a single, complex signal; the receiver recovers the
   >   separate signals, a process called demultiplexing (or demuxing).

   What does "multiplexed" mean in "multiplexed async architecture"?
2. Given that "when you can do no more until one or more of the pending I/O operations completes, the thread running your code goes into a blocking wait", how is "multiplexed async architecture" asynchronous?

Answer (score 2):

> The meaning of "multiplexed" in "multiplexed async" can't be explained by its definition

Yes, but it's pretty close. The meaning is:

> Multiplexing is a way of performing multiple operations using a single thread at the same time.

What this architecture does is similar to [time-division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing).

---

> Given that "when you can do no more until one or more of the pending I/O operations completes, the thread running your code goes into a blocking wait", how is "multiplexed async architecture" asynchronous?

[Wikipedia defines "asynchrony" as:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming))

> Asynchrony […] refers to the occurrence of […] actions instigated by a program that take place concurrently with program execution, without the program blocking to wait for results.

That is what's happening in this case. That blocking is used as an implementation detail doesn't matter. What matters is that while one operation is waiting, others can continue.

Comment: Thanks. How does "multiplexed async architecture" achieve "asynchronous"? In "multiplexed async architecture", "when you can do no more until one or more of the pending I/O operations completes, the thread running your code goes into a blocking wait", and blocking wait is not asynchronous.

Comment: @Tim Blocking wait until a specific operation completes is indeed not asynchronous. But using a blocking wait until *any* operation completes makes the whole system asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "using a blocking wait until any operation completes makes the whole system asynchronous"?

Comment: Hi @svick, Thanks. Could you explain again how "multiplexed async architecture" achieves "asynchronous"? Specifically, "using a blocking wait until any operation completes makes the whole system asynchronous"?